# React Native version mismatch - only when compiled in Android Studio - works in METRO

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, apk, metro-bundler

I recently updated my react native app to version 0.61.5. The old version was 0.59.3

Everything was working fine while I was doing the upgrades. Then, I tried to make a signed APK and submit for beta testing to Android Store. That APK did not work on any of my android devices. It just gave a blank white screen on open - javascript failed.

Later, I was able to replicate the error, and get actual and virtual devices to show this red screen (see image), even for testing, whenever the app is built exclusively in Android Studio.

Error reads: 
console.error: "React Native version mismatch.

JavaScript version: 0.59.3
Native version: 0.61.5
etc...

When I "npm run start" in the terminal, outside Android Studio, it starts up the Metro bundler. Then everything works fine, both real and virtual devices. Somehow the Metro bundler is able to reconcile something but Android Studio's bundler is not.

Since Android Studio's APK generator uses it's native javascript bundler, I need to figure out why this is happening, and fix it.

I have tried 
 - clearing caches, deleting the project, invalidating caches, watchmen etc.
 - adding implementation ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5") {force = true} (in build.gradle)
 - many other solutions given for this error message found on stack overflow...

2 days on this. No idea.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGwQC.jpg)

Comment: have you using **aab** file for beta testing?

Comment: in terminal run the given command
"killall node" and then run your project again

Comment: Yes, I submitted an aab for beta testing. Both it and APK's cause the white screen error. I ran a grep command on it and found it to be the same react native version mismatch error, that I am able to replicate now.

Comment: killall didn't work